# In SQL Server how to Pivot for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is my sample table, I want to pivot the category column and get the sales, stock and target as rows

[image]

I want the sample output in this form as shown in the  below wherein the categories are in place of columns and columns in place of row

[image]

Answer (score 49):

You gotta change the name of columns for next Pivot Statement.

Like

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Branch,
   Category,
   Category+'1' As Category1,
   Category+'2' As Category2,
   Sales, 
   Stock, 
   Target
  FROM TblPivot
 ) AS P

 -- For Sales
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Sales) FOR Category IN ([Panel], [AC], [Ref])
 ) AS pv1

 -- For Stock
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Stock) FOR Category1 IN ([Panel1], [AC1], [Ref1])
 ) AS pv2

 -- For Target
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Target) FOR Category2 IN ([Panel2], [AC2], [Ref2])
 ) AS pv3
 GO
```

---

You are ready to go now....

You can use aggregate of pv3 to sum and group by the column you need.

Comment: The key point here is that you create new category values by appending `1` or `2` to the end.  Without doing this, the pivot query won't work properly.

Answer (score 26):

Sample Table :

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Branch varchar(9), Category varchar(9), Sales INT,Stock INT,Target INT)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Branch, Category, Sales, Stock,Target)
VALUES
    ( 'mumbai', 'panel', 10,4,15),
    ( 'mumbai', 'AC', 11,7,14),
    ( 'mumbai', 'Ref', 7,2,10),
    ( 'Delhi', 'panel',20,4,17),
    ( 'Delhi', 'AC', 5,2,12),
    ( 'Delhi', 'Ref', 10,12,22)
;
```

IN SQL SERVER Script :

```
  Select BRANCH,COL,[panel],[AC],[Ref] from (
    select Branch,Category,COL,VAL from @Table1
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Sales',Sales),
    ('Stock',Stock),
    ('Target',Target))CS (COL,VAL))T
    PIVOT (MAX(VAL) FOR Category IN ([panel],[AC],[Ref]))PVT
ORDER BY Branch DESC
```

Comment: This only works if the columns (here Sales, Stock, Target) have the same data type.

Answer (score 6):

Try below solution

```
  -- Applying pivoting on multiple columns
SELECT
*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Category,
   Sales, 
  FROM TblPivot
 ) AS P

 -- For Sales
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Sales) FOR Category IN ([Panel], [AC], [Ref])
 ) AS pv1

union all

 -- For Stock
 SELECT
*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Category,
   Stock, 
  FROM TblPivot
 ) AS P

 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Stock) FOR Category IN ([Panel], [AC], [Ref])
 ) AS pv2

union all

 -- For Target
 SELECT
*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Category,
   Target, 
  FROM TblPivot
 ) AS P

 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Target) FOR Category IN ([Panel], [AC], [Ref])
 ) AS pv3
 GO
```

Comment: I got 'Invalid column name 'Category'. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 6):

From [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50442967/1019435) & [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067653/1019435)

(this not OP's requirement)

[image]

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(Branch varchar(9), Category varchar(9), Sales INT,Stock INT,Target INT);

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Branch, Category, Sales, Stock,Target)
VALUES
    ( 'mumbai', 'panel', 10,4,15),
    ( 'mumbai', 'AC', 11,7,14),
    ( 'mumbai', 'Ref', 7,2,10),
    ( 'Delhi', 'panel',20,4,17),
    ( 'Delhi', 'AC', 5,2,12),
    ( 'Delhi', 'Ref', 10,12,22);

SELECT
    Branch,
    SUM(Panel) As PanelSales,SUM([AC]) As ACSales,SUM([Ref]) As RefSales,
    SUM(Panel1) As PanelStock,SUM([AC1]) As ACStock,SUM([Ref1]) As RefStock,
    SUM(Panel2) As PanelTarget,SUM([AC2]) As ACTarget,SUM([Ref2]) As RefTarget
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Branch,
   Category,
   Category+'1' As Category1,
   Category+'2' As Category2,
   Sales, 
   Stock, 
   Target
  FROM @Table1
 ) AS P

 -- For Sales
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Sales) FOR Category IN ([Panel], [AC], [Ref])
 ) AS pv1

 -- For Stock
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Stock) FOR Category1 IN ([Panel1], [AC1], [Ref1])
 ) AS pv2

 -- For Target
 PIVOT
 (
   SUM(Target) FOR Category2 IN ([Panel2], [AC2], [Ref2])
 ) AS pv3
 Group BY Branch
 GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Following should work,

```
select * FROM
(
  SELECT 
   Branch,
   Category,
   Sales, 
   Stock, 
   Target
  FROM Table1
 ) AS P
 unpivot
 (
 [Value] FOR [OutPut] IN (sales,stock,[target])
 )unpvt
 pivot
 (
 max([Value]) for  Category in (Panel,AC,Ref) 
 )pvt
order by Branch Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first `UNPIVOT` the data to make it a flat table and then `PIVOT` to turn the categories into columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Output IN (Sales, Stock, Target)) upvt
PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR Category IN (Panel, AC, Ref)) pvt
ORDER BY Branch, Output;
```