# How to Pivot multiple columns into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a sample query data table:

[image: Sample data]

I want my output table to look like:

[image: Output sample data]

I tried by using pivot operator but its not possible to sum them all.

Comment: The sample data and Output Sample data highlighted in blue are the links to the images of the respective tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-sever-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns  .. same question been again asked !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM woddb.cityStock_Unpivot
    ) AS tblCity
    UNPIVOT
    (
        OutputValue FOR [OutputFieldName] IN (Sales, stock, [Target])
    ) AS UNPVT
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(OutputValue)
        For Category IN (Panel,ac,ref)
    ) AS PVT
```