# MSSQL Pivot on two Columns

Tags: sql-server

Hey so I'm trying to pivot two columns if you see my code below I was able to perform my pivot on one column. is there a way to pivot my ReturnedItems column right next to ShippedItems?

Thank you

```
declare @t table (
store varchar(20),
ShippedItems int,
ReturnedItems int
)

insert into @t
values ('Walmart',1,2)
insert into @t
values ('Lowes',1,2)
insert into @t
values ('Home Depot',1,2)

select * from (
select * from @t
) pivottable
pivot
(
sum(ShippedItems)
for store in (Walmart,Lowes,[Home Depot])
) x
```

Comment: What is the desired layout/results ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Sql Server how to Pivot for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT 
    Walmart_ShippedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Walmart' THEN t.ShippedItems END),
    Walmart_ReturnedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Walmart' THEN t.ReturnedItems END),
    Lowes_ShippedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Lowes' THEN t.ShippedItems END),
    Lowes_ReturnedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Lowes' THEN t.ReturnedItems END),
    HomeDepot_ShippedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Home Depot' THEN t.ShippedItems END),
    HomeDepot_ReturnedItems = MAX(CASE WHEN t.store = 'Home Depot' THEN t.ReturnedItems END)
FROM
    @t t
```

HTH,
Jason