# Using PIVOT to aggregate monthly counts of products purchased and revenue generated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've searched this site and have done Google searches for how to pivot multiple columns (sales counts and revenue by month), but haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I admit that I haven't completely wrapped my head around PIVOT-ing yet, so it's possible I just wasn't fully understanding a solution that has already been posted.

What I'm trying to do is construct a query using PIVOT that will show monthly counts, as well as monthly revenue for products purchased.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Product | MonthPurchased | InvoiceNmber | PaymentAmount
====================================================
Pencil          1             10001           1.00 
Pencil          2             10005           1.00 
Pen             1             10002           2.00  
Paper           2             10006           1.00  
Pen             1             10003           2.00
Paper           1             10004           1.00
```

Here is the query I've put together:

```sql
INSERT INTO #temp_nbcc_products
        ( [Product], [Month], t_invoice_num, t_payment_amount )

SELECT prd_name, DATEPART(mm, pyd_add_date), invoice_num, payment_amount
FROM product_table ...

SELECT [Product]
    , [1] AS Jan
    , [2] AS Feb
    , [3] AS Mar
    , [4] AS Apr
    , [5] AS May
    , [6] AS June
    , [7] AS July
    , [8] AS Aug
    , [9] AS Sept
    , [10] AS Oct
    , [11] AS Nov
    , [12] AS Dec
    , [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] AS [Total Count]
FROM
    (
    SELECT t_payment_amount, t_invoice_num, [Month], [Product]
    FROM #temp_nbcc_products
    ) src

PIVOT

    (
     COUNT(t_invoice_num)
     FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
    ) piv1

ORDER BY [Product] DESC;
```

Here is the output of the query:

```
Product | Jan | Feb | March .... Total Counts
=============================================
Pencil     1     1      0             2
Pen        2     0      0             2
Paper      1     1      0             2
```

What I'd like the result set to look like is this:

```
Product | Jan | Revenue-Jan | Feb | Revenue-Feb .... TotalCounts | TotalRev
========================================================================
Pencil     1       1.00        1       1.00               2          2.00
Pen        2       4.00        0       0.00               2          4.00
Paper      1       1.00        1       1.00               2          2.00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think conditional aggregation is easier:

```
SELECT product,
       sum(case when [Month] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when [Month] = 1 then t_payment_amount else 0 end) as jan_revenue,
       sum(case when [Month] = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
       sum(case when [Month] = 2 then t_payment_amount else 0 end) as feb_revenue,
       . . .
FROM #temp_nbcc_products
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you know how to use PIVOT.

Using `GROUP BY` Just make your base dataset before the PIVOT looks like:

```
Product | MonthPurchased | TotalMonthCount| TotalPaymentAmount
====================================================
Pencil          1             2              1.00 
Pencil          2             2              1.00
```

Then you can do the PIVOT for multiple columns.

[In Sql Server how to Pivot for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns)