# Select to find the path of Products in single row (Pivot with unaggregated and null values) SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this there could be multiple products with varying path

| Product | StartPoint | EndPoint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | A | B |
| P1 | B | C |
| P1 | C | D |
| P1 | D | E |
| P1 | E | F |
| P2 | P | Q |
| P2 | Q | R |
| P2 | R | S |
| P2 | S | T |

I want output like this Path Points could vary for different products

| Product | PP1 | PP2 | PP3 | PP4 | PP5 | PP6 | PP7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | null |
| P2 | P | Q | R | S | T | null | null |

I find the similar question but couldn't solve this one
[In Sql Server how to Pivot for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns)

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: Do you mean you want A, B, C etc in _separate columns_, or together in one column?

Comment: why are you changing from text to image ? Please do not use image. We can't copy & paste the information for testing at all

Comment: @jarlh could you please see the question again? I have formatted it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use recursive cte to find the path. And use `PIVOT` to present the information horizontally

```
with rcte as
(
    -- Anchor Member. Find the Starting point of the path
    select Product, t.StartPoint, t.EndPoint, path = 1
    from   tbl t
    where  not exists
           (
               select *
               from   tbl x
               where  x.Product = t.Product
               and    x.EndPoint = t.StartPoint
           )
           
    union all
    
    -- Recursive Member
    select t.Product, t.StartPoint, t.EndPoint, path = path + 1
    from   rcte r
           inner join tbl t on  t.Product    = r.Product
                            and t.StartPoint = r.EndPoint
)
select Product, 
       [1] as [PP1], [2] as [PP2], [3] as [PP3], [4] as [PP4], 
       [5] as [PP5], [6] as [PP6], [7] as [PP7]
from
(
    select Product, Point = StartPoint, path
    from   rcte
    
    union all
    
    -- include the last point
    select Product, Point = EndPoint, path + 1
    from   rcte r
    where  not exists
           (
               select *
               from   tbl x
               where  x.Product = r.Product
               and    x.StartPoint = r.EndPoint
           )
) d
pivot
(
    max(Point)
    for [path] in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) p
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=752370d828f9349b19e928bf9ba4323d)

---

[EDIT : dynamic sql version]

```
-- Find the max no of paths
declare @col_count int;

select  @col_count = max(cnt) + 1
from
(
    select  Product, cnt = count(*)
    from    tbl
    group by Product
) t;

-- Form the columns string
declare @sql nvarchar(max),
        @col_1 nvarchar(1000),
        @col_2 nvarchar(1000);
        
with cols as
(
    select n = 1
    union all
    select n = n + 1
    from   cols
    where  n < @col_count
)
select @col_1 = string_agg(quotename(n) + ' AS ' + stuff(quotename(n), 2, 0, 'PP'), ','),
       @col_2 = string_agg(quotename(n), ',')
from   cols;

print @col_1;
print @col_2;

select @sql = 
N'with rcte as
(
    select Product, t.StartPoint, t.EndPoint, path = 1
    from   tbl t
    where  not exists
           (
               select *
               from   tbl x
               where  x.Product = t.Product
               and    x.EndPoint = t.StartPoint
           )
           
    union all
    
    select t.Product, t.StartPoint, t.EndPoint, path = path + 1
    from   rcte r
           inner join tbl t on  t.Product    = r.Product
                            and t.StartPoint = r.EndPoint
)
select Product, ' + @col_1 + '
from
(
    select Product, Point = StartPoint, path
    from   rcte
    
    union all
    
    select Product, Point = EndPoint, path + 1
    from   rcte r
    where  not exists
           (
               select *
               from   tbl x
               where  x.Product = r.Product
               and    x.StartPoint = r.EndPoint
           )
) d
pivot
(
    max(Point)
    for [path] in (' + @col_2 + ')
) p'

-- Print out for verification
print @sql

-- Execute the query
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

[db<>fiddle Dynamic SQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=273e3f649ab4119bc379a359a0ff4118)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.
Is there a way to dynamically add columns?
There might be few products with more than 7 columns.

Comment: you will need to generate the query dynamically and execute it with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)