# Can I create 2 columns per row when pivoting in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have data like this:

```
ID   | Ref | Value1 | Value2
-----+-----+--------+--------
1    | R1  | 1R11   | 1R12
1    | R2  | 1R21   | 1R22
2    | R1  | 2R11   | 2R12
2    | R2  | 2R21   | 2R22
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
ID   | R1-Value1 | R1-Value2 | R2-Value1 | R2-Value2
-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
1    | 1R11      | 1R12      | 1R21      | 1R22
2    | 2R11      | 2R12      | 2R21      | 2R22
```

This seems at least similar to a pivot to me, but from reading around it doesn't seem like it's something `PIVOT` supports. Is that correct, or have I missed something?

Additional:
The two main things I'm having trouble with are

1. Generating two columns from one row i.e. "R1-Value1" and "R1-Value2" both come from a single row
2. I would like the Ref values I query on to be easily changeable. e.g. sometime I want results for R1 and R2, sometimes for R3 and R4 and R5, for a large number of possible combinations.

Comment: Yes, you could. `PIVOT`ing or conditional aggregation is exactly what you need (I recommend the latter). There are plenty of examples of doing this; what about those existing questions didn't you understand or what was your attempt and why didn't it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SQL Server how to Pivot for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns)

Comment: The only thing I've found so far is to combine the Value1 and Value2 columns with something like CONCAT(Value1, 'safe_separator', Value2), pivot on that combined column and then split that column into two. But that seems hacky, inefficient, and difficult to scale to lots of ref values.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic conditional aggregation, aka `PIVOT`. But it's often easier to do the aggregation using `MIN(CASE WHEN` rather than the official `PIVOT` operator, as it's far more flexible that way, for example to pivot on two columns at once.

In this case, you want to be able to specify the two `Ref` values dynamically

```sql
DECLARE @FirstRef varchar(30) = 'R1';
DECLARE @SecondRef varchar(30) = 'R2';

SELECT
  t.ID,
  FirstRefValue1  = MIN(CASE WHEN t.Ref = @FirstRef  THEN t.Value1 END),
  FirstRefValue2  = MIN(CASE WHEN t.Ref = @FirstRef  THEN t.Value2 END),
  SecondRefValue1 = MIN(CASE WHEN t.Ref = @SecondRef THEN t.Value1 END),
  SecondRefValue2 = MIN(CASE WHEN t.Ref = @SecondRef THEN t.Value2 END)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f3c2412ad9df0b077614d693c671f03)

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I've found looking around and I was hoping that there was something better/easier. With this method I'll have to generate the query dynamically depending on how many refs I want and what their values are.
It is useful to know that this is the way though.

Comment: What you could do is have a fixed query with say 10 columns, and some of them will just be `NULL`. Using dynamic SQL is fraught with difficulties and security issues, avoid if you can. Certainly using dynamic SQL is going to be *more* complicated than this

Comment: Yes, I meant using dynamic SQL to basically generate this SQL but with the relavant references. Fortunatley for me I've found a way to avoid the whole pivot/dynamic thing in the code I'm working on.

Comment: @Dan - It would be nice if you explained that.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s very specific to what I’m working on so not much use to anyone else. There are still pivots, but outside the bit I’m making reusable.