# SQL pivot multiples columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

| TT | ID | No | Date_input | BR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06041098 | 780000 | 01/01/2015 | 111 |
| 2 | 01506000299 | 780000 | 11/07/2022 | 111 |
| 1 | 06048903 | 783111 | 01/01/2015 | 123 |
| 2 | 015173000562 | 783111 | 04/25/2023 | 123 |
| 1 | 01517300 | 792523 | 02/02/2022 | 150 |
| 2 | 011105981 | 792523 | 03/21/2022 | 150 |
| 3 | 0346166413164 | 792523 | 04/25/2023 | 150 |

I am having "Mytable" above and would like to get pivot, and my syntax is:

```
select no, br, \[1\] as ID1, \[2\] as ID2, \[3\] as ID3
from (select TT, id, no, Br from Mytable) Table_Pivot
pivot
(min(ID) for TT in (\[1\] , \[2\] , \[3\])) bang
```

However, I would like add Date_input in my pivot as result show below

| NoB | Br | ID1 | Date_input1 | ID2 | Date_input2 | ID3 | Date_input3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 780000 | 111 | 06041098 | 01/01/2015 | 01506000299 | 11/07/2022 |  |  |
| 783111 | 123 | 06048903 | 01/01/2015 | 015173000562 | 04/25/2023 |  |  |
| 792523 | 150 | 01517300 | 02/02/2022 | 011105981 | 03/21/2022 | 0346166413164 | 04/25/2023 |

Comment: Don't ask a new question, edit your existing question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Tks BonCodigo, but ur answer not match my request

Comment: [How to pivot multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (in SQL Server) to achieve "pivots" of multiple columns is to do it the old way with "conditional aggregates" (case expressions inside aggregate functions) e.g.

```
-- Traditional Pivot query using conditional aggregates
SELECT No AS NoB,
       BR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 1 THEN ID END) AS ID1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 1 THEN Date_input END) AS Date_input1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 2 THEN ID END) AS ID2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 2 THEN Date_input END) AS Date_input2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 3 THEN ID END) AS ID3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 3 THEN Date_input END) AS Date_input3
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY No, BR;
```

| NoB | BR | ID1 | Date_input1 | ID2 | Date_input2 | ID3 | Date_input3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 780000 | 111 | 06041098 | 2015-01-01 | 01506000299 | 2022-11-07 | *null* | *null* |
| 783111 | 123 | 06048903 | 2015-01-01 | 015173000562 | 2023-04-25 | *null* | *null* |
| 792523 | 150 | 01517300 | 2022-02-02 | 011105981 | 2022-03-21 | 0346166413164 | 2023-04-25 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yfHjUHIA)

For formatting dates to mm/dd/yyyy (style number 101)

```
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 1 THEN ID END) AS ID1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar, Date_input, 101) END) AS Date_input1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 2 THEN ID END) AS ID2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 2 THEN CONVERT(varchar, Date_input, 101) END) AS Date_input2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 3 THEN ID END) AS ID3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN TT = 3 THEN CONVERT(varchar, Date_input, 101) END) AS Date_input3
```

Comment: Tks Maxwel, I have done this with ur traditional suggestion.