# How to use float AND nvarchar values together inside PIVOT in MAX() aggregation function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such an SQL:

```sql
SELECT p.PID,
       p.HitIndex,
       p.Smiles,
       p.EntityID,
       pp.mw AS MW,
       pp.heavyatoms AS HeavyAtoms,
       pp.tpsa AS TPSA,
       pp.lipinskihba AS Lipinskihba,
       pp.lipinskihbd AS Lipinskihbd,
       pp.rotb AS RotB,
       pp.xlogp AS XlogP,
       pp.ro5 AS RO5,
       pp.bbbarcode AS BBBarcode
FROM (SELECT pr.PID,
             p.HitIndex,
             p.Smiles,
             p.EntityID,
             (CASE WHEN PropVal IS NULL THEN PropStrVal ELSE PropVal END) AS PropVal,
             PropName
      FROM V_DELProdProps pr
          JOIN DELProducts p ON p.PID = pr.PID) Temp
PIVOT (MAX(PropVal)
       FOR [PropName] IN ([mw], [heavyatoms], [tpsa], [lipinskihba], [lipinskihbd], [rotb], [xlogp], [ro5], [bbbarcode])) pp
    JOIN DELProducts p ON pp.PID = p.PID;
GO
```

What I want is to feed inside the MAX aggregation function `float` and `nvarchar` for different columns, but I am not sure how to do that correctly, how I can restructure the query.

Here is some data for `V_DELProdProps`:

[image]

And for `DELProducts`:

[image]

Here is an example output. The only thing that needed to be fixed here is getting correct values for the `BBBarcode`:

[image]

As you can see `PID`s are not duplicate in the result and that's how it should be.

Comment: Sample data and expected results/behaviour will help us help you.

Comment: can you add some data as we don't know how PropStrVal  looks like, and can you not convert PropStrVal  to float

Comment: I added two screenshots with the data. Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: please show example and expected with text

Comment: I added example output. The only thing that needs to be fixed is correct `BBBarcode` retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi-pivot technique from this question [In SQL Server how to Pivot for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns):

```
with tmp as (
  select id, prop_name, prop_val, prop_str_val,
         prop_name as prop_name_bar
  from v_DelProdProps )
select id, max(tpsa) tpsa, max(rot) rot, max(bbbarcode) bbarcode from tmp
pivot (max(prop_val) for prop_name in ( [TPSA], [ROT]) ) as pvt1
pivot (max(prop_str_val) for prop_name_bar in ( [BBBarcode]) ) as pvt2
group by id
```

or use standard conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
        max(case when prop_name = 'TPSA' then prop_val end) tpsa,
        max(case when prop_name = 'ROT' then prop_val end) rot,
        max(case when prop_name = 'BBBarcode' then prop_str_val end) tpsa
from v_DelProdProps 
group by id
```

or cast everything to nvarchars at first and do it like you did:

```
with tmp as (
  select id, prop_name, 
         case when prop_val is null then prop_str_val 
              else cast(prop_val as nvarchar(50)) 
         end prop_val
  from v_DelProdProps )
select * from tmp
pivot (max(prop_val) 
       for prop_name in ( [TPSA], [ROT], [BBBarcode]) ) as pvt
```

[dbfiddle demo for all queries](https://dbfiddle.uk/hxth4v3x)

In second solution you have to be careful, I don't know if for the same ID and prop_name there can be two entries, for example TPSA 70 and TPSA 500. In this case you need aggregation is needed at first, because '70' is greater than '500' when compared as strings.

I simplified your data, because most of the columns are not relevant to main problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PID, p.HitIndex, p.Smiles, p.EntityID,
    pp.mw as MW,
    pp.heavyatoms as HeavyAtoms,
    pp.tpsa as TPSA,
    pp.lipinskihba as Lipinskihba,
    pp.lipinskihbd as Lipinskihbd,
    pp.rotb as RotB,
    pp.xlogp as XlogP,
    pp.ro5 as RO5,
    pp.bbbarcode AS BBBarcode
FROM
(
    SELECT pr.PID, p.HitIndex, p.Smiles, p.EntityID,
        (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(PropVal) = 1 THEN CAST(PropVal AS FLOAT) ELSE NULL END) AS PropVal_Float,
        PropVal,
        PropName,
        bbbarcode AS BBBarcode
    FROM V_DELProdProps pr
    JOIN DELProducts p ON p.PID = pr.PID
) AS Temp
PIVOT
(
    MAX(PropVal_Float) FOR [PropName] In ([mw], [heavyatoms], [tpsa], [lipinskihba], [lipinskihbd], [rotb], [xlogp], [ro5], [BBBarcode])
) AS pp
JOIN DELProducts p ON pp.PID = p.PID;
```

Comment: It does not work because it leads to duplication of rows: no aggregation happens over nvarchar columns. Plus `BBBarcode` is not retrieved, its `NULL` but I need to get values for it.

Comment: i did edit of code .. try this

Comment: This one gives a syntax error: `Invalid column name 'bbbarcode'.` See also the data that is stored in the tables: just updated the question.

Comment: change the column name according to your req

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: bbbarcode - check this column name on your side and add in the query

Comment: pp.bbbarcode AS BBBarcode

Comment: There is no such column in the query that you posted, so that is not possible, it may need to be restructured further. The error happens inside the `Temp` table. See the sample data that I posted, it will help clarifying that.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the BBBarcode column, you can add it to the Temp subquery otherwise you can remove it

Comment: I don't know how it is possible, please, add it if you know how to.