# Pivot multiple columns into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was recently tasked with finding a way to getting a number of start date and end dates to be pivoted into their own columns based on an ID.
Here is the how the data currently is in our database.

| EmpID | Task ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18499 | 6457 | 3/27/2014 | 10/17/2014 |
| 18499 | 7588 | 10/17/2014 | 12/23/2015 |
| 18499 | 12788 | 12/23/2015 | 10/5/2016 |
| 18499 | 16856 | 10/5/2016 | 10/30/2016 |
| 18499 | 17051 | 10/30/2016 | 1/19/2017 |

As you can see the EmpID has a distinct list of tasks. Each task has a start date and an end date. This particular employee has 5 tasks but not everyone will have 5. Some may have 1, some 10, etc.

Here is what my supervisor wants it to look like.

| EmpID | Start1 | End1 | Start2 | End2 | Start3 | End3 | Start4 | End4 | Start5 | End5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18499 | 3/27/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 12/23/2015 | 12/23/2015 | 10/5/2016 | 10/5/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 1/19/2017 |

Basically each EmpID will have one row with each of their start and end dates.

Here is what I was able to find looking around online.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select [EmpID]
              ,[TaskID] = concat(''TASKSTART'', ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [EmpID] ORDER BY [TaskID]))
              ,[Start_Date]
         From #YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (min([Start_Date]) For [TaskID] 
 in (' 
 + Stuff((Select Distinct ','
 +QuoteName(concat('TASKSTART',ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [EmpID] ORDER BY [TaskID])))
                                               From #YourTable  
                                               Order by 1
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Now this nicely returns each of the Task Start Dates in a row like a I want it.

| EmpID | TASKSTART1 | TASKSTART2 | TASKSTART3 | TASKSTART4 | TASKSTART5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18499 | 3/27/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 12/23/2015 | 10/5/2016 | 10/30/2016 |

But I can't figure out how to also include the End Dates how I want it. I know it has something to do with the Pivot (min([Start_Date]) for [TaskID]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns

Comment: @BartMcEndree i've reused your link for duplicate vote, thanks

Comment: There is where you tell your supervisor that this can be solved much easier in a client/reporting application.

Comment: @BartMcEndree why not add it as an answer, no need to be shy

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks for the vote of confidence in my proposed solution

Comment: If this is for presentation to a human, do it in your application (presentation layer), not on your relational database.  If it's for further processing within SQL, don't do it at all, this is an anti-pattern, and SQL is specifically designed to manipulate normalised data (your starting format). Either way, this is a code-smell / anti-pattern, and should not be done.

Comment: To clarify your issue, please update your example to include more employees and tasks. We need to know if TASKSTART1 should be populated for all employees. For example: add employee 18500 with task 6457 and employee 18501 with task 1234.

Answer (score 1):

I find it is easier to solve these problem by making a non-dynamic version first. Now we just need to replace the column names with the Task IDs using your Exec(@SQL) trick.

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable 
(
    EmpID   INT,
    TaskID  VARCHAR(512),
    Start_Date  VARCHAR(512),
    End_Date    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable (EmpID, TaskID, Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES
    (18499, '6457', '3/27/2014', '10/17/2014'),
    (18499, '7588', '10/17/2014', '12/23/2015'),
    (18499, '12788', '12/23/2015', '10/5/2016'),
    (18499, '16856', '10/5/2016', '10/30/2016'),
    (18499, '17051', '10/30/2016', '1/19/2017');

SELECT * FROM #YourTable 

select EmpID
       ,Max([6457start])  as TASKSTART1, Max([6457end])  as TASKEND1
       ,Max([7588start])  as TASKSTART2, Max([7588end])  as TASKEND2 
       ,Max([12788start]) as TASKSTART3, Max([12788end]) as TASKEND3
       ,Max([16856start]) as TASKSTART4, Max([16856end]) as TASKEND4
       ,Max([17051start]) as TASKSTART5, Max([17051end]) as TASKEND5
From
(
  
Select *
 From (
        Select [EmpID]
              ,[TASKID] + 'Start' as TaskStart  
              ,TASKID +'end' as TASKEnd
              ,[Start_Date]
              ,[End_Date]
         From #YourTable
      ) A
       
 Pivot
(
 min([Start_Date]) For TaskStart in ([6457start],[7588start],[12788start],[16856start],[17051start])
) as pv1
  
Pivot 
(
  min([End_Date]) For TASKEnd in ([6457end],[7588end],[12788end],[16856end],[17051end])
) as pv2
  
) B
GROUP BY EmpID
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oSNc-sc3)

| EmpID | TASKSTART1 | TASKEND1 | TASKSTART2 | TASKEND2 | TASKSTART3 | TASKEND3 | TASKSTART4 | TASKEND4 | TASKSTART5 | TASKEND5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18499 | 3/27/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 12/23/2015 | 12/23/2015 | 10/5/2016 | 10/5/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 1/19/2017 |

Comment: Hi Bart. So your solution is fine for just this one little employee ID when we know what the task ID's are. 
However that was just my example to show you all what I was talking about.
I really need to do this for about a thousand employeeIDs. I'm not going to know what each one's taskID is nor does everyone just have 5 tasks. They could have 1 or more.

Comment: I added more employee examples and tested it https://dbfiddle.uk/GehjsMhl

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Your just using the same taskID's for different empID's. In the database Each EmpID is unique to each employee, and each TaskID is unique to each employee.

Comment: So we need to handle a much greater variety of task IDs https://dbfiddle.uk/PBiy8lpf

Comment: Sorry not what I'm looking for. Your solution is fine for hardcoding and knowing what each employees task id's are, but in my database I have over 37,000 task ids. I'm not going to list each one out.

Comment: @litteLunker You would populate the task ids by constructing the query as a string and executing via Exec(@SQL). I think you can figure out that part. Loop thru SELECT distinct TaskID from #YourTable.

Comment: That’s why I’m asking the question. I don’t know how

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    EmpID   INT,
    TaskID  VARCHAR(512),
    Start_Date  VARCHAR(512),
    End_Date    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO MYTABLE 
(EmpID, TaskID, Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES
(18499, '6457', '3/27/2014', '10/17/2014'),
(18499, '7588', '10/17/2014', '12/23/2015'),
(18499, '12788', '12/23/2015', '10/5/2016'),
(18499, '16856', '10/5/2016', '10/30/2016'),
(18499, '17051', '10/30/2016', '1/19/2017');
```

in your case you don't need `multiple pivot`,use `pivot`,`concat` and `PARSENAME` as follows

```
select 
EmpID,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([6457],'|','.'),2) TASKSTART1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([6457],'|','.'),1) TASKEND1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([7588],'|','.'),2) TASKSTART2,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([7588],'|','.'),1) TASKEND2,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([12788],'|','.'),2) TASKSTART3,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([12788],'|','.'),1) TASKEND3,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([16856],'|','.'),2) TASKSTART4,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([16856],'|','.'),1) TASKEND4,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([17051],'|','.'),2) TASKSTART5,
PARSENAME(REPLACE([17051],'|','.'),1) TASKEND5

from 
(
  select EmpID,TaskID, concat(Start_Date,'|', End_Date) p
  from MYTABLE  yt 
) src
pivot
(
  max(p)
  for TaskID in ([6457],[7588],[12788],[16856],[17051])
) piv;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dndawpR)

Answer (score 0):

This should be portable across a bunch of different DBMS-s:
First, get a row number, using the OLAP function `ROW_NUMBER()`, then pivot around the emp id and flatten using the `MAX(CASE WHEN ...` method - and group by the emp id:

```
WITH
-- your input data ...
indata(EmpID,Task_ID,Start_Date,End_Date) AS (
          SELECT 18499, 6457,DATE '03/27/2014',DATE '10/17/2014'
UNION ALL SELECT 18499, 7588,DATE '10/17/2014',DATE '12/23/2015'
UNION ALL SELECT 18499,12788,DATE '12/23/2015',DATE '10/5/2016'
UNION ALL SELECT 18499,16856,DATE '10/05/2016',DATE '10/30/2016'
UNION ALL SELECT 18499,17051,DATE '10/30/2016',DATE '01/19/2017'
)
-- end of input, real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
w_rn AS (
  SELECT
    empid
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY start_date) AS rn
  , task_id
  , start_date
  , end_date
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  empid
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN start_date END) AS start1
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN end_date   END) AS end1
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN start_date END) AS start2
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN end_date   END) AS end2
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN start_date END) AS start3
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN end_date   END) AS end3
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 4 THEN start_date END) AS start4
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 4 THEN end_date   END) AS end4
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 5 THEN start_date END) AS start5
, MAX(CASE rn WHEN 5 THEN end_date   END) AS end5
FROM w_rn
GROUP BY empid;
```

| empid | start1 | end1 | start2 | end2 | start3 | end3 | start4 | end4 | start5 | end5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18,499 | 2014-03-27 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-17 | 2015-12-23 | 2015-12-23 | 2016-10-05 | 2016-10-05 | 2016-10-30 | 2016-10-30 | 2017-01-19 |

Comment: Does this work if you have multiple employees?

Comment: Here is a version of your query that works any number of tasks https://dbfiddle.uk/kVq4JP6N

Comment: It absolutely works. I `PARTITION BY empID ORDER BY start_date` to get the row number - so it starts counting from 1 with every new empID. And at the end, I `GROUP BY` empID again.

Comment: I really like this one as well. It works really well with multiple empID's

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #yourtable
FROM
(
    VALUES  (18499, 6457, N'3/27/2014', N'10/17/2014')
    ,   (18499, 7588, N'10/17/2014', N'12/23/2015')
    ,   (18499, 12788, N'12/23/2015', N'10/5/2016')
    ,   (18499, 16856, N'10/5/2016', N'10/30/2016')
    ,   (18499, 17051, N'10/30/2016', N'1/19/2017')
    ,   (19000, 123, N'10/30/2023', N'1/19/2023')
) t (EmpID,[Task ID],Start_Date,End_Date)

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
Select *
 From (
    select EmpID, y.Start_date, y.label
    from (
            Select  *
            ,   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [EmpID] ORDER BY [Task ID]) AS id
            From    #YourTable y
            ) x
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  CONCAT(''Start'', id) AS label
            ,   Start_date
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CONCAT(''End'', id) AS start
            ,   End_Date
        ) y
      ) A
 Pivot (min([Start_Date]) For [label] 
 in (' 
 + Stuff((SELECT    ','+QuoteName(concat(x.label,row_id))
               FROM (
            SELECT  DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [EmpID] ORDER BY [Task ID]) row_id
            FROM    #YourTable y
            ) m
               CROSS apply (
            SELECT  'Start' AS label, 1 AS sort
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  'End' AS label, 2 AS sort
        ) x
               ORDER BY [row_id], x.sort
               FOR XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
EXEC    (@SQL);
```

I create two rows from one for the pivot foundation, containing Start and End date, and then by using your original CONCAT code, i create the start/end labels which is used to make the pivot. This also handles multiple employees.

Output:

| EmpID | Start1 | End1 | Start2 | End2 | Start3 | End3 | Start4 | End4 | Start5 | End5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18499 | 3/27/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 10/17/2014 | 12/23/2015 | 12/23/2015 | 10/5/2016 | 10/5/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 10/30/2016 | 1/19/2017 |
| 19000 | 10/30/2023 | 1/19/2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

There's probably a more efficient solution if you put your soul into it, but in my opinion, one shouldn't use pivot because it gets unreadable fast with too many columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I’m looking for! However I was wondering if you can explain how Cross Apply works? I’ve never used it before and everything I look up shows it as a join in the where clause. I see yours shows no where clause. Idk if we can email or something

Comment: It's like a join but inside of apply you have the outside columns available to you so it's very handy for various things, here I use it to create two rows from one by using a UNION inside the APPLY.