Pivot table returning split rows, how can I group them correctly into 1 row
CREATE TABLE #table1  (orderid nvarchar(256), itemid varchar(10),productid nvarchar(256), ProductDesc varchar(max))
insert into #table1
values
('001323232','1','ABC30013', 'LOVESEAT 3PC'),
('001323232','2','DFE30013', 'SOFA DINING SET')
--select * from #table1

Select *
From
(
    Select  
    'HG-KKSHGSRMN1XHG'as measurement_id ,
    'purchase' as event_name    ,
    'https://www.test.com/' as [event_param.page_hostname], 
    '1665100800' as timestamp_micros,
    'offline' as [event_param.campaign_name],
    'In-Store Sales' as [event_param.campaign_source]   ,


        OrderId, 
        ProductId as ProductId,
    --  ItemId as ItemId
       ProductDesc as ProductDesc,
      --  concat('item',row_number() over (partition by Orderid order by productid)) as ItemId_ProductId,
        'item'+cast(Itemid as varchar) + '.item_name' as ItemId_ProductDesc, 
        'item'+cast(Itemid as varchar) + '.item_id' as ItemId_ProductId 
    FROM #table1  
    group by OrderId, ItemId, ProductId, ProductDesc

) src

PIVOT
(
   MAX(ProductId)
   For ItemId_ProductId in ([item1.item_id],
                            [item2.item_id]
                            )
) mypivot


PIVOT
(
   MAX(ProductDesc)
   For ItemId_ProductDesc in ([item1.item_name],
                              [item2.item_name]
                            )
) mypivot2


These lines are repeated coming from a normalized table.  In this case, the client wants the OrderId unique on 1 line, and any attributes dynamically added in sequence left to right.  The ItemId is the unique ID for each item attribute column pre-fix on the order.  So OrderNumber, then item1.x, item2.y, and so on.
I was creating MULTIPLE repeatable columns to hit it again and it kind of works using PIVOT, but it has a bunch of NULL values spaced out in rows.  I tried groupings but couldn't group them up.  The NULLS space out the results.  If the NULLs all went away, and it grouped up, it would look correct.
How can I get ProdDesc next to Productid grouped into 1 line for the order?

First try a hardcoded pivot then follow examples on how to make it dynamic. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067490/in-sql-server-how-to-pivot-for-multiple-columns

declare #table table (orderid nvarchar(256), itemid varchar(10),sku nvarchar(256), productDesc varchar(max) )
insert into #table
values
('001323232','1','ABC30013','television 50in'),
('001323232','2','DFE30013', 'radio boombox 24amp')
how does it flatten with dynamic columns without adding NULLs,?
@BartMcEndree

Select *
From
(
Select  OrderId,
ProductId as ProductId,
-- ItemId as ItemId
-- ProductDesc as ProductDesc,
--    'item'+cast(Itemid as varchar) + '.item_name' as ItemId_ProductDesc,
'item'+cast(Itemid as varchar) + '.item_id' as ItemId_ProductId
FROM #table1
) src
PIVOT
(
MAX(ProductId)
For ItemId_ProductId in ([item1.item_id], [item2.item_id]
)
) mypivot   *This works exactly how I want it to, BUT when I introduce the secondary ItemId call in the concat string, it splits them out assuming the Item 1 and 2 are getting split out.

Try https://dbfiddle.uk/LE6bz-5u.
